# Apache - Location vs Directory Directives

Tags: apache

Im not that familiar with Apache.

- When using `<Location>`, I am able to redirect users to a sign-on page, forcing them to authenticate and have proper privileges before accessing the **URL**.
- When using `<Directory>`, it is supposed to allow me to control access to specified **folders and directories**, right?

**Question:**
How does `<Directory>` behave similarly and differently from `<Location>`?

- With `<Location /web>`: www.mysite.com/web and www.mysite.com/web/foo will be controlled.
- With `<Directory /webforms>`: how will www.mysite.com/web look like if some of the scripts are from that folder?
- With `<Directory /pictures>`: how will www.mysite.com/web look like if some of the picture are from that folder?
- What about a situation where you have both types of directives active and affecting a single page? What kinds of things should I expect or watch out for?

Comment: I believe you are asking for precedence of Location versus Directory.  The answers to your questions and more are here:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html .   (see how sections are merged, but you should read the entire page).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Apache HTTP server documentation has a section called [**What to use When**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#whichwhen) which, I think, directly answer your question :

> Choosing between filesystem containers and webspace containers is actually quite easy. When applying directives to objects that reside in the filesystem always use `<Directory>` or `<Files>`. When applying directives to objects that do not reside in the filesystem (such as a webpage generated from a database), use `<Location>`.

The important part is the following :

> It is important to never use `<Location>` when trying to restrict access to objects in the filesystem. This is because many different webspace locations (URLs) could map to the same filesystem location, **allowing your restrictions to be circumvented**.

[Read on](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#whichwhen) for more information...