# Apache authtype Basic not working on 1 out of 50 hosts

Tags: apache, basic-authentication

We have a server with about 120 vhosts, around 50 of them are password protected. All vhost configuration is scripted through Ansible.

A vhost with working password protection is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName staging.website1.demohub.site
    ServerAlias origin.staging.website1.demohub.site

    ServerAdmin jd@automatem.co.nz

    DocumentRoot /var/www/staging.website1.org.nz/trunk

    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId sta_website1 sta_website1
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /var/www/staging.website1.org.nz/apachelogs/staging.website1.org.nz-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/staging.website1.org.nz/apachelogs/staging.website1.org.nz-error.log

    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        CGIPassAuth on
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9270/
    </FilesMatch>

     Alias "/robots.txt" "/var/www/norobots.txt"
     <Directory /var/www/staging.website1.org.nz>
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/staging.passwd
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Review security udpates"
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    <Location /info.php>
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/staging.passwd
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Review security udpates"
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    Alias "/info.php" "/var/www/info.php"
</VirtualHost>
```

A couple of days ago on one vhost password protection did not work

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName staging.websitenameis22chars22.demohub.site
    ServerAlias origin.staging.websitenameis22chars22.demohub.site

    ServerAdmin jd@automatem.co.nz

    DocumentRoot /var/www/staging.websitenameis22chars22.org.nz/trunk

    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId sta_usernameis12 sta_usernameis12
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /var/www/staging.websitenameis22chars22.org.nz/apachelogs/staging.websitenameis22chars22.org.nz-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/staging.websitenameis22chars22.org.nz/apachelogs/staging.websitenameis22chars22.org.nz-error.log

    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        CGIPassAuth on
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9364/
    </FilesMatch>

     Alias "/robots.txt" "/var/www/norobots.txt"
     <Directory "/var/www/staging.websitenameis22chars22.org.nz">
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/staging.passwd
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Review security udpates"
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

#    <Location /info.php>
#       AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/staging.passwd
#       AuthType Basic
#       AuthName "Review security udpates"
#       Require valid-user
#   </Location>
#   Alias "/info.php" "/var/www/info.php"
</VirtualHost>
```

Through trial and error we found that if we add Location block as well

```
 <Location />
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/staging.passwd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Review security udpates"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

password protection works on this vhost as well.

What is the cause for password protection to not work without Location

Other apache custom configuration:

```
FileETag none

Timeout 120
KeepAliveTimeout 4
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
ServerLimit 512

<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
  StartServers             5
  MinSpareServers          5
  MaxSpareServers         10
  MaxRequestWorkers      150
  MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>


# Prevent SVN and git downloads
<Directory ~ ".*\.(svn|git)">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
</Directory>

<FilesMatch ".*~$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @Nico Haase The website is served without password protection. I have checked website logs and apache error log. Have not found anything that would point to a problem. Because of the scripted configuration I suspect a problem with some sort of limit.

Comment: 1 out of 50 did not work.  The only difference is that the info.php section was commented out?  A classic problem with multi-virtualhost configurations is thinking we are in VH12 when we are in fact in VH1.  Remember that if apache does not find the VH you expect (wrong domain, typo, ...) it reverts back to the first it finds on top of your configuration file.  That is why I like to setup that first VH with a nice error page so I know it was used.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395439/apache-location-vs-directory-directives

Comment: @nico3500 no, the commenting out is part of the trial and error. It does not affect it. Its certainly not a vhost mixup and there is an error vhost at aaaaaaaaaaaa.somedomain.com. Secondly - yes, I do not want the workaround with a Location block, hence I've put up a question here.

Comment: Just checking assumptions: The content for **staging.websitenameis22chars22.demohub.site** *really is* in or under **/var/www/staging.websitenameis22chars22.org.nz/trunk** from the file system's point of view, right?

Comment: @Don R yes, and the website is delivering traffic as expected and that traffic is logged where it should be. It just doesn't have Auth on it

Comment: @Don R I have all folders in the clients site's DNS name, but for the vast majority of staging/ testing site's I use our own demohub.site domain, because we control the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration **seems** like it ought to work.

So, it is either a [file limit problem](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/fd-limits.html) (even if this should show in the logs), which you can diagnose by e.g. temporarily disabling other **non-protected** websites to free up file handles, or some other weird kind of limit problem (this can be confirmed by disabling other **protected** websites, once the first check has failed).

It might also be some silly happenstance - I half remember some trouble I got into, years ago, because I had not noticed that a 0xA0 character had been slipped in somehow after a file name. Visually the name was something.pl, but actually it was something.pl , so not a Perl file after all. Since it's easy to do, check the configuration file to ensure it's all visible ASCII. I'd even go so far as to check that "udpates" in the AuthName - shouldn't make a difference, and definitely not a non-logged one AFAIK, and it *is* the same as the reference, but... just in case, pulling straws for pulling straws' sake, try with "updates".

If nothing works I would start swapping configuration and directories between this site and another which works, and then swapping back one item at a time, and see when the authentication mishap switches back on. Also, before this, change the configuration file names so they are loaded in a different order. This has often served me in good stead when investigating such poltergeists.